# How to delete a file containing "æøå" (special danish chars) in the filename through QueryString?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, query-string

I´m trying to delete a file containing "æøå" in the filename:

```
private void DeleteFile(HttpContext context)
    {
        var filePath = context.Server.MapPath(StorageRoot) + context.Request["f"];

        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            File.Delete(filePath);
        }
    }
```

..and the url:

```
"/FileTransferHandler.ashx?f=Cambridge_Freestyle Priser 2015 16-22 år.pdf&type=DELETE"
```

It´s working if the filename doesn´t contain "æøå":

```
"/FileTransferHandler.ashx?f=Cambridge_Infoblad om Cambridge.pdf&type=DELETE"
```

How do I get this to work with filenames containing "æøå", special chars?

Comment: Always good to verify the file name does not contain path chars `../` etc

Comment: I appreciate the pointers. @Allan S. Hansen So as you say, I would need to first decode the letter "å" in the QueryString in the example above? How would I go about that?